# how to call a name via boolean

Tags: java, boolean

I want to call the name of the person who has CEO = true;    which in this case is Tristen.
How would I go about this?
I have already converted the public String name and public boolean CEO to Static.

What i'm trying to reach is that it would look like this

system.out.printIn("Your CEO is Tristen");

```
public class business {

public static String name;
public String lastname;
public String email;
public String department;
public static boolean CEO;
public boolean employee;
public boolean assistant;
public boolean head;
public boolean manager;

public static void main(String[]args){


    business tristen;
    business jan;
    business robert;
    business kevin;
    business ben;

    tristen = new business();
    tristen.name = "Tristen";
    tristen.lastname = "Korsuize";
    tristen.email = " ";
    tristen.department = "Magic";
    tristen.CEO = true;
    tristen.employee = false;
    tristen.assistant = false;
    tristen.head = false;
    tristen.manager = false;

    jan = new business();
    jan.name = "Jan";
    jan.lastname = "Lindenberg";
    jan.email = "Jan002_003@hotmail.com";
    jan.department = "Magic";
    jan.CEO = false;
    jan.employee = false;
    jan.assistant = false;
    jan.head = false;
    jan.manager = true;

    robert = new business();
    robert.name = "Robert";
    robert.lastname = "Irving";
    robert.email = " ";
    robert.department = "Magic";
    robert.CEO = false;
    robert.employee = false;
    robert.assistant = true;
    robert.head = false;
    robert.manager = false;


    if(business.CEO = true){
        System.out.println("Your CEO is"+ " "+ business.name);
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using == in your if statement?

Comment: @nickecarlo He should just be deleting the `= true` part :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Either way it doesn't do what he needs. Which, for the love of Pete, I don't know the point of actually.

Comment: remove static from `public static String name;` and `public static boolean CEO;`

Comment: @nickecarlo Yes, OP is obviously writing her first ever Java program :) Some random fields are `static`---I bet they got that way by Eclipse Quick Fix :)

Comment: indeed they did marko.

Comment: @SandraVernon I always warn my students against taking Quick Fix as an advisor---its purpose is to save time to a developer who already knows exactly what they want.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Kudos to the OP then since my first Java program contained some 3 lines. And to the OP, dump Eclipse or turn off auto-correct/help features and try to understand the code and why things are the way they are.

Comment: @nickecarlo I would never advise working with raw text of source code. Nobody sane writes import statements by hand, for example. You can't jump to declarations, you don't get error-as-you-type, and so on. A beginner will be best served by an IDE tailor-made for beginners, like BlueJ.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I see. I've never worked on BlueJ. Started on TextWrangler and now work on IDEA. In my personal experience working with TextWrangler, where the only nicety I got was color coded code, has been a lot more rewarding because I had to worry about the errors and look through the documentation to see where I was wrong. But on the other hand, it was also one of the most infuriating experiences of my short programming life.

Comment: @nickecarlo Yes, that would be the "tough love" approach to learning :)

Answer (score 3):

I would put the people in a collection and iterate over that e.g.

```
List<business> businesses = new ArrayList<business>();
// add people here...

foreach (business b : businesses) {
   if (b.isCEO()) {
     System.out.println(b);
   }
}
```

Some additional comments:

1. Java naming convention suggests you should capitalise your class names e.g. `Business`
2. your members are public. I would make them private and instantiate via the constructor. This promotes encapsulation - a key feature of OO programming. expose them via methods (to hide the implementation)
3. ask the object if it's a CEO - don't pull the field out and decide it yourself. See the example above
4. I would try not to use `static`. All the info you have is tied up in your objects.

Comment: `public final` fields may actually be OP's cup of tea.

Comment: In the objects ? I still don't think that's particularly good. I'd promote methods wherever possible. Or am I misunderstanding you ?

Comment: Yes, I guess for a beginner the best advice is accessors; I'm just personally sick of them and need positive evidence of an actual concern they take care of for me before allowing them in.

Comment: Scala or any other language made since the year 2000 :) I prefer Clojure to Scala, BTW.

Answer (score 2):

The `CEO` and `name` fields should not be static. A static field means that the value is given to all instances of the `business` class, not just the individual instance. For example;

```
tristen = new business();
tristen.CEO = true;

jan = new business();
jan.CEO = false;  //CEO is now false for all instances of business (tristen and jan)
```

You might want to store all your instances in some sort of [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) as your create them, then afterwards you can iterate through the collection and check which one is CEO.